# How to upgrade python inside a docker container

Tags: docker

Is it possible to upgrade python inside a docker container? I tried to use apt update and also to update a running container but getting repository does not have a release file and also update from such repository can't be done securely. New to docker.

Tried to also curl docker tar ball. but it doesn't move at all comparing it to running curl outside the container.

Comment: better to use offical image with required version https://hub.docker.com/_/python

Comment: i'm using girder and got the notice about python 2.7 deprecation when I logged in and tried to attach some plugins to it.

Comment: clone their [repo](https://github.com/girder/girder), update Dockerfile, build it

Comment: you can use `docker run -it --name my python python:3.7-alpine3.9` use this image having 3.7 python version and you will not get warning